# Objects stuck at top of stage and won't fall down

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, animation

I am using math.random to randomly drop objects from the top of the stage.  I had it working with one object. But as I wanted to increase the number to 6 objects, I added the following code:  But I am "stuck" and so are the 6 objects at the top of the stage. What am I doing wrong here?  I appreciate the help.

```
            private function bombInit(): void {
                roachBombArray = new Array();
         for (var i:uint =0; i < numBombs; i++) {
                roachBomb= new RoachBomb();
                    roachBomb.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                    roachBomb.vy = Math.random() * 2 -1;
                    roachBomb.y = -10;
                    addChild(roachBomb);
                    roachBombArray.push(roachBomb);
         }

                    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEntry);
                }

                private function onEntry(event:Event):void {
                    for (var i:uint = 0; i< numBombs; i++) {

                var roachBomb = roachBombArray[i];

                vy += ay;
                roachBombArray[i] += vy;


                if (roachBombArray[i] > 620) {
                removeChild(roachBombArray[i]);
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEntry);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're removing your enterFrame listener when the first bomb goes off the bottom, at which point you're no longer listening for ENTER_FRAME events and updating any of your bombs.

You don't want to remove this listener until you're done animating ALL the bombs.

UPDATE: How I would expect things to look, incorperating Ethan's observation that you ought to use the local roachBomb that you declare...

```
public class BombDropper extends Sprite {

    private static const GRAVITY:int = 1; // Set gravity to what you want in pixels/frame^2
    private static const BOTTOM_OF_SCREEN:int = 620;
    private var numBombs:int = 6;
    private var roachBombArray:Array;

    // ... constructor and other class stuff here

    private function bombInit(): void
    {
        roachBombArray = new Array();

        for (var i:int =0; i < numBombs; ++i)
        {
            var roachBomb:RoachBomb = new RoachBomb();
            roachBomb.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
            roachBomb.vy = Math.random() * 2 -1;
            roachBomb.y = -10;
            this.addChild(roachBomb);
            roachBombArray.push(roachBomb);
        }

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEntry);
    }

    private function onEntry(event:Event):void
    {
        for each ( var roachBomb:RoachBomb in roachBombArray)
        {
            roachBomb.vy += GRAVITY;
            roachBomb.y += vy;

            if (roachBomb.y > BOTTOM_OF_SCREEN)
            {
                this.removeChild(roachBomb);
                roachBombArray.splice(roachBombArray.indexOf(roachBomb),1);
                if (roachBombArray.length == 0)
                {
                    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEntry);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh silly me!  I removed that but now I've got a 1034 cannot convert. I will research this error now....thank you, Adam.

Comment: You probably also need removeChild(roachBombArray[i] as DisplayObject); Arrays aren't typed, so the compiler does not know what roachBombArray[i] is.

Comment: Ok I did that.  I also did removeChild(roachBombArray[i].roachBomb) and both of these got me the same result...those bombs are still stuck at the top of the stage, wont' budge.  lol

Comment: I updated my response just now with an example of how I might implement this system, making use of the roachBombArray to maintain the references to the active bombs, such that no attempt is made to remove the same bomb more than once (your original example doesn't reset each bomb's y position when it gets removed as a child, so it will attempt to re-remove bombs over and over since y stays greater than 620 and you are still looping over all bombs).

Comment: Woohoo. Oh thanks Adam and Ethan. Sorry I'm just getting back to you. Those bombs are dropping now. I just need to put in a loop and I'm good and happy.  :-) I've got 3 book to refer to but you guys are far better than these books!!!!

Comment: Hello Adam.  I was able to add a regeneration loop on the end of the script like so:  if (roachBomb.y > 620) {
   roachBomb.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
   roachBomb.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
            roachBomb.vy2 = Math.random() * 2 -1;
   roachBomb.ay2 = Math.random() * 2 -1;
            roachBomb.y = -20;
   }

Comment: The statement "roachBomb.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;" will have no effect since you call "roachBomb.y = -20;" right after. I'm also not sure why you now have vy2 and ay2, rather than resetting vy and ay. In any case, if you need bombs to continue falling, you are definitely correct to have a pool of them and re-use them like this, rather than abandon them to be GC'd and instantiate new ones.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add the velocity to the RoachBomb rather than to the RoachBomb y position.

```
roachBombArray[i] += vy;
```

should be

```
roachBombArray[i].y += vy;
```

Additionally you create a local variable:

```
var roachBomb = roachBombArray[i];
```

but you never manipulate it.
Perhaps you meant to do something like this?

```
var roachBomb:RoachBomb = roachBombArray[i]; // I added the type to the local variable
roachBomb.vy += ay;
roachBomb.y += vy; // Manipulate the local variable
if (roachBomb.y > 620) {
removeChild(roachBomb);
}
```

Comment: roachBombArray[i] += vy; Heh, yeah, that would also be a problem :-)

Comment: It should also be roachBomb.vy += ay; I'm sure the intent was not to have one commonly declared vy for all the bombs which gets incremented numBombs times per frame! ay that is common to all makes sense though (gravity being constant and all).